# How can File.toURI().toURL() throw an exception?

Tags: java, url, exception

I noticed that `File.toURL()` is deprecated in favour of `File.toURI().toURL()`.  (I am using Java 8.)

I see `URI.toURL()` can throw `MalformedURLException` (extends `IOException`).

Under what conditions can `File.toURI().toURL()` throw an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it's possible. For example, consider this program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(protocol -> {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        });

        System.out.println(new File("/etc/passwd").toURI().toURL());
    }
}
```

Here `toURL` call actually fails with `MalformedURLException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089)
    at com.example.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.example.Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:17)
    at java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(URL.java:1142)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:599)
    ... 4 more
```

However I doubt that your program will function correctly anyways if you set custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` which does not support even `file` scheme.

With default `URLStreamHandlerFactory` I cannot think up or remember cases when `toURL` may fail, so if you don't mess with `URLStreamHandlerFactory`, you can use it safely.

If you need to produce `URL` objects often, you may consider creating some utility method like this:

```
public class FileUtils {
    public static URL toURL(File file) {
        try {
            return file.toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it everywhere. It just asserts that `MalformedURLException` is impossible in your program, so if it actually occurs, it will be considered as internal program error.

Another possibility is not to use `URL` class at all. For many purposes the `URI` class can be used instead.

Comment: Before reading your answer, I never knew about `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()`.  Excellent.